# GCP vision API text detection null response but has response using website demo

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, vision

recently I'm using GCP vision API to detect a image that has subtitle or not(chinese character).

What's strange is that when detect with GCP sdk in my code, it respond no text, even that I can see subtitle there obviously.

Then I tried uploading that image directly to the official website DEMO manually([link here](https://cloud.google.com/vision)).
It responded the subtitle text exactly what it is.

Below is my sample code

```js
export class GCPVisionAPI implements TextDetectorAPI {
  visionClient: ImageAnnotatorClient;

  async ApiInit(GCPCredential: string | undefined) {
    if (!GCPCredential) {
      throw new Error('Invalid GCP Credential!');
    }
    const credentialParams = {
      credentials: JSON.parse(GCPCredential),
    };
    this.visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentialParams);
  }

  async detect(imageBuffer: Buffer) {
    try {
      const [result] = await this.visionClient.textDetection(imageBuffer);
      const fullTextAnnotation = result.fullTextAnnotation;

      if (fullTextAnnotation) return true;
      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

To sum up my question, the text detection result is not consistent between sdk and website demo.
Any one bump into this problem before?

Comment: Please provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Such as your code.

Comment: @TimChiang update my class for calling the API. Please take a look, thank you!

Comment: Have you referred to this [quickstart code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision_text_detection_gcs-nodejs) for TEXT_DETECTION in Vision API ?

Comment: I just realized that you're using `result.fullTextAnnotation`, how about `textAnnotations`? I check out this [AnnotateImageResponse](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse), also check out sample on [github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/blob/HEAD/samples/detect.js), they use `result.textAnnotations;` for detecting text.

Comment: thank you guys, let me give a few tries.

Comment: Hi @高欣平, Did the above comments help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I use both `documentTextDetection` and `textDetection` to increase accuracy. Because I found sometimes just one of them detect text in the image.(I only need to detect whether there is text or not, no need to detect what the text is.) Maybe give some feedback after a few weeks test.

Comment: Can you provide an example where only one of them detects the text in the image?

Comment: the code in my question is only one of them, I'll post both of them below.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my final method, also to answer @prajnaRai.
So far everything works fine.
To clarify some misunderstanding, there is no big difference between `textAnnotation` and `fullTextAnnotation`.
The only difference is that `textAnnotation` return in array, `fullTextAnnotation` return in string.

```
async textDetect(imageBuffer: Buffer) {
    try {
      // 2 types of text detection, use both to get more accurate detection
      const [documentResult] = await this.visionClient.documentTextDetection(imageBuffer);
      const [textResult] = await this.visionClient.textDetection(imageBuffer);
      const documentFullTextAnnotation = documentResult.fullTextAnnotation;
      const textAnnotation = textResult.fullTextAnnotation;

      if (documentFullTextAnnotation || textAnnotation) return true;
      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
      return false;
    }
  }
```